# RegEx help to change properties in CSS

Tags: css, regex

I ned some help with RegEx, not sure what I am doing wrong.
What I would like to achieve is to change the value of one CSS property in a CSS file without altering anything within that CSS file.

```
<?php
$var = '
#css {
    text-size: 14px;
    color: red;
    background: orange;
}
';
echo preg_replace('/#css(.*)color: (.*);(.*)}/is','#css$1color: black;$3 }',$var);
?>
```

The result I am hoping to see is this:

```
#css {
    text-size: 14px;
    color: red;
    background: orange;
}
```

However what I get is this:

```
#css {
    text-size: 14px;
    color: black;
 }
```

I am not an expert in RegEx at all but after reading manuals and examples online I thought I could use backreferences to do this and that $1 would be the result of the first match, $2 of the second, $3 of the third etc... In my example $1 matches everything between '#css' and 'color: ' and then $2 I don't use because I want to replace 'red' with 'black'. I thought $3 would be the result of everything between ';' and '}' but it gets lost somewhere or, more likely, I am lost somewhere ;-)

Thanks for the advice and support.

Comment: _“The result I am hoping to see is this”_ … different from what you are staring with how exactly?

Comment: do you want to change the color property only in the given css code... please confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, using the greedy `.*` is always problematic. In your case, it cosumes too much symbols so that you lose the background because it matches the last `;` in your code (which comes after the background declaration). Instead use a negative character class which matches until the very next symbol you know should not be included in the match - in your case the `;`. So the character class should look like: `[^;]*`. The same is true with matching the `}` symbol - use a negative character class instead.

Secondly, I would try to reduce the usage of capture groups.

And finally, I would reduce the clutter and put everything you don't want to replace into the capturegroups before and after so that you get a very simple result: `'$1black$2'`

Try the following regex:

```
preg_replace('/(#css.*?color:)[^;]*([^}]*)/is','$1black$2',$var);
```

[See the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ba9a2557198414a5c0cc9b4dec2204a1613db66)

Note that this regex has one flaw: If you have different `color`s in your decplarations (background-color, border-color,...), it will break! So you should include an additional whitespace to make sure it only captures the "real" `color` declaration:

```
/(#css.*?\scolor:)[^;]*([^}]*)/is
```

This still might break if (which should not happen) per accident you have multiple `color:xyz;` declarations in your rule block. Only the first one gets replace then.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I am a newbie at RegEx so I can't say I really get it all but I do appreciate you taking the time to explain what you have done and I get the general gist of it for sure. This code works great and I will make sure that my code doesn't have any double color definitions, which would be useless in CSS anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: Chrisoph, your solution works great for me, but could you help me change this RegEx so I can also use it to change background colors of CSS definitions such as:  ".menu li" or "#div content" or  "ul li"?

Comment: @marcnyc sure, just change `\scolor` to `\sbackground-color`.

Comment: I probably didn't explain myself correctly... the issue is not the color or background color, the issue is that instead of changing the color or background color of #css I would like to change the the colors of a span such as ".menu li" or of a div such as "#div content" or of a list such as "ul li"... if in your code I replace "#css" with ".menu li" the code breaks and I am not sure how I can change it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're [matching greedily for your second capture group](http://regexr.com?375ac). In doing so, it consumes everything up until the final semicolon in your text.

What you should be doing instead is [using a lazy matching group instead](http://regexr.com?375af) which will match as few characters as possible. (eg. only up until the *first* semicolon, rather than the last)

```
preg_replace('/#css(.*)color: .*?;(.*)}/is','#css$1color: black;$2 }',$var);
```

Comment: +1 correct solution. I prefer (negative) characterclasses instead of the `.` (see my answer) but nonetheless it fixes the problem. http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, I think this will solve your issue.

```
$var = '
#css {
    text-size: 14px;
    color: red;
    background: orange;
}
';
preg_match_all('/(#css\s*\{[\sA-z0-9#:;-]*color\s*:\s*[A-z0-9#]*)/', $var, $output);

$temp = preg_replace('/(color\s*:\s*[A-z0-9#]*)/im', 'color: black', $output[0][0]);

echo preg_replace('/(#css\s*\{[\sA-z0-9#:;-]*color\s*:\s*[A-z0-9#]*)/im', $temp, $var);

?>
```